# Zoom resize in Flash Gesture

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, zooming

I have limits in zoom, so you can make zoom from 100% to 150%. But, I make the zoom, then I pan to the right-top of the zoomed MC and then when I zoom out, the MC stays at left, and the MC disappear from the screen. I can't see the MC anymore.

How can I zoom out the MC, without going the `Stage`? Here is my code for zoom:

```
function onZoom(e:TransformGestureEvent):void {

    var MIN_ZOOM:Number = 1; //minimal zoom percentage 100%
    var MAX_ZOOM:Number = 1.5; //maximal zoom percentage 150%

    escenario.scaleX *= e.scaleX;
    escenario.scaleY *= e.scaleY;
    escenario.scaleX = Math.max(MIN_ZOOM, escenario.scaleX);
    escenario.scaleY = Math.max(MIN_ZOOM, escenario.scaleY);
    escenario.scaleX = Math.min(MAX_ZOOM, escenario.scaleX);
    escenario.scaleY = Math.min(MAX_ZOOM, escenario.scaleY);

}
```

It's pinch zoom gesture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the `x` and `y` properties too. If the position of the `MovieClip` is out the `Stage` bounds, then you need to correct them.

> If you are working with `Classes` and the `MAX_ZOOM` and `MIN_ZOOM` are `constants`, is recommendable to declare them like they are. This code assumes that you have your `MovieClip` in the `root`, you want to maintain it inside the `Stage` bounds and the `MovieClip` with scale of 1 have the same size as the `Stage`, change the code depending of your layout.

```
private const MIN_ZOOM:Number = 1;
private const MAX_ZOOM:Number = 1.5;

private function onZoom(e:TransformGestureEvent):void {

    var scale:Number = Math.min(e.scaleX, e.scaleY);

    escenario.scaleX *= scale;

    // Check if the scale is between the min and max parameters
    if(escenario.scaleX > MAX_ZOOM) escenario.scaleX = MAX_ZOOM;
    if(escenario.scaleX < MIN_ZOOM) escenario.scaleX = MIN_ZOOM;

    escenario.scaleY = escenario.scaleX;

    // Check is the MovieClip is inside the Stage bounds
    if(escenario.x > 0) escenario.x = 0;
    if(escenario.y > 0) escenario.y = 0;
    if(escenario.x + escenario.width < escenario.stage.stageWidth) escenario.x = escenario.stage.stageWidth - escenario.width;
    if(escenario.y + escenario.height < escenario.stage.stageHeight) escenario.y = escenario.stage.stageHeight - escenario.height;

}
```